# Prepend CSS class to @import with Less

Tags: less

I'm trying to prepend a CSS class to all of the imported CSS using Less, but I can't get it to apply to comma separated selectors.

This is the Less I'm using:

**style.less**

```
.myStyle {
    @import "imported.less";
}
```

**imported.less**

```
.styleA {}
.styleB {}
.styleC, .styleD {}
```

**The Output**

```
.myStyle .styleA {}
.myStyle .styleB {}
.myStyle .styleC, .styleD {}
```

**Desired Output**

```
.myStyle .styleA {}
.myStyle .styleB {}
.myStyle .styleC, .myStyle .styleD {}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you using to compile less into css? I'm using [koala](http://koala-app.com/) and it compiles into the desired css.

Comment: Your code works as expected in the reference Less compiler just fine. So you're probably just using some exotic or very outdated one.

Comment: @seven-phases-max  I'm using less on PHP with this framework:  https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php, which claims to use the official less processor.  I have to use PHP for the project, but I'm open to switching to other less PHP processors if there is a better alternative.

Comment: `less.php` should compile your example correctly. So make sure the code in your example (it's simplified, right?) is equal to the one you see the issue in (for instance there's [known related Bootstrap issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1826) - but the story there is quite different).

Comment: @seven-phases-max the known bootstrap issue you linked is exactly the problem.  I switched to `@import (less) "imported.css"` with better results.  If you want to post an answer I'll gladly accept it to increase your imaginary internet points total.

Comment: that would be too complicated - since your Q does not really describe the issue I would have to describe it myself and then answer it. Too much text, sorry :) But what's more important is that there're already [enough Q&As](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+bootstrap+prefix) dedicated to Bootstrap prefixing/namespacing (which is in its turn in fact 3 or 4 different issues in one).